# Chartjs - make line start at ... but maintain x-axis data

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart

I created a dynamic line chart based on some input data. The intention is that the customer can indicate with a dropdown on which month the "Investment" should start.

So, for example, if the "Investment" does not start until month 6, then that line should only start at 6 on the x-axis. But the other lines "Case" and "ROI" should still just start at 1.

I've tried several things but to no avail.

I tried changing the x-axis "min ticks" based on the selection the user made, but that makes all lines start at another point instead of the "Investment" line only. Another problem is that every number before the selection then dissapears from the x-axis. But I really want to keep every number from 1-60, even if the user chooses to start the "Investment" on month 10, for example.

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/js5pha24/

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Case',
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(152,164,135, 0.5)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(152,164,135)',
      fill: false
    }, {
      label: 'Case',
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(145,139,167, 0.5)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(145,139,167)',
      fill: false
    }, {
      label: 'Case',
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(206,157,206, 0.5)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(206,157,206)',
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "top"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          autoSkip: true,
          maxRotation: 0,
          minRotation: 0
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          callback: value => {
            return "€ " + value;
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
  options.data.labels.push(i);

  const caseMonth = 118187 * i;
  options.data.datasets.find(set => set.label === "Case").data.push(caseMonth);

  const investMonth = 500000 + (20000 * i);
  options.data.datasets.find(set => set.label === "Investment").data.push(investMonth);

  const roiMonth = caseMonth - investMonth;
  options.data.datasets.find(set => set.label === "ROI").data.push(roiMonth);
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas { background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put **null** values on the chart data so one line can start after the others. For example if you want the investment line start at month 10, you can replace the the first ten investMonth values with **null**.

If understood correctly you still want to use the investMonth value in the roiMonth calculation so I created "investMonthValue" so only investment will get null if it is less than investmentStartMonth.

```
let investmentStartMonth = 10

for (let i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
    options.data.labels.push(i);

  const caseMonth = 118187 * i;
  options.data.datasets.find(set => set.label === "Case").data.push(caseMonth);

  let investMonth = 500000 + (20000 * i);
  let investMonthValue = i<investmentStartMonth?null:investMonth
  options.data.datasets.find(set => set.label === "Investment").data.push(investMonthValue);

  const roiMonth = caseMonth - investMonth;
  options.data.datasets.find(set => set.label === "ROI").data.push(roiMonth);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This indeed solves the problem. Didn't know it was that simple.